# fixed position not working correctly within Google App on iOS10

Tags: ios, css, iphone, google-search

**Background**

There is an iOS app, just called "Google – Search made just for mobile"(it's some sort of internal browser within this app). Our team was asked to support it.

We have a button, which should be placed at the bottom of the view, so we chose `position: fixed` with `bottom: 60px` to have this requirement work.

**Evnironment**

device: iPhone7
iOS: 10.3.3
goole app: 33.0.164895372

**Issue**

Safari: work
Chrome: work
Google-app: not work. Seems google-app's internal browser never know the right viewport height, while giving a vertical scrolling, the button either display at the correct place, or just missing(lower than the real viewport bottom line)

> I even tried `position: absolute` with a parent container(full size of the screen), but no luck

Has anyone seen the issue before? How should we fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue in Google App on iOS. A 100% height website with an absolutely positioned element above and below.

**Cause**

The viewport height in Google App is detected correctly, but Google App put's by default at the top his address bar over the website and at the bottom some other bar as wel over the website. So these elements, that belong to the Google App, are like absolutely positioned elements over your website.

However, when you open the website the Google App "scrolls down" a bit the website, so that the top of the website comes under the address bar (otherwise the top of your website would be hidden. This however pushes the entire website like 30px down which, with a 100% height website, makes it look like the viewport is 100% + 30px. The moment you scroll a bit the address bar at the top and the other bar at the bottom disappear and the website will show perfectly.

**Workaround**

Add a directive to the body that readjusts the height of the app to the innerheight of the viewport. Worked in my case.

```
<body force-full-height>
      <!-- Your content -->
</body>
```

...

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('my.directives', []);

    app.directive('forceFullHeight', forceFullHeight);

    forceFullHeight.$inject = [
        '$window',
        '$rootScope'
    ];

    function forceFullHeight($window, $rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
                function onResize() {
                    element.css('height', $window.innerHeight + 'px');
                };

                function cleanUp() {
                    angular.element($window).off('resize', onResize);
                }

                angular.element($window).on('resize', onResize);
                scope.$on('$destroy', cleanUp);

            scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', onResize());
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google App version 57.0 on iOS fixed the issue.
Header bar and footer bar now change height of webview.